# How can I access to services outside the cluster using kubectl proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kube-apiserver

When we spin up a cluster with kubeadm in kubernetes, and the service's `.yaml` file looks like this :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neo4j
  labels:
    app: neo4j
    component: core
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 7474
      targetPort: 7474
      name: browser
    - port: 6362
      targetPort: 6362
      name: backup
  selector:
    app: neo4j
    component: core
```

After all pods and services run, I do `kubectl proxy` and it says :

```
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

So when I want to access to this service like :

```
curl localhost:8001/api/
```

it's just reachable inside the cluster! How can I reach to services outside the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expose your service using NodePort:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neo4j
  labels:
    app: neo4j
    component: core
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 7474
      targetPort: 7474
      name: browser
    - port: 6362
      targetPort: 6362
      name: backup
  selector:
    app: neo4j
    component: core
```

Now if you describe your service using

```
 kubectl describe svc neo4j
```

You will get a nodeport value which will be in between 30000-32767 and you can access your service from outside the cluster using

```
curl http://<node_ip>:<node_port>
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Yes you can't directly use `clusterIP: None` in case of exposing service through NodePort. Now `clusterIP: None` means there is no internal load balancing done by kubernetes and for that we can also use `externalTrafficPolicy=Local` in service definition.

Alternatively, you might be able to use an ingress to route traffic to the correct Service.

Comment: In this way, should I delete the line `clusterIP: None` ?

Comment: I have edited my service definition in answer. Please have a look